# Creating and deleting cron jobs in python

Tags: python, cron

So I have a little script I wish to run once a week.  It will check on some variable and if its set, it continues running the script, if not, I want it to wait an hour and try again.  If it's still not set, it'll wait 2 hours, then 4, and then give up for the week.  My question is, can I do this in python?  Seems like I'd have to create and delete cron jobs in python to get this to work.

Comment: why exactly do you need to do this using cron? what prevents you from sleeping inside the python code?

Comment: Well, I don't want to hold any resources hostage on the machine if I don't have to...I don't know too much about how python sleep works though so if it's fine, I guess I can do that.

Comment: I would say sleeping wouldn't cost much overhead if any but if you're still worried you can try Daniel's solution. it also has the advantage that you can always restart your computer..

Answer (score 1):

You can't really set standard crons directly from Python. Instead, I'd set the cron to fire every hour, and in the code determine if it needs to run again (ie last successful execution is more than 7 days ago).

Comment: and you can save the last execution time to a file in some configuration directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Time.sleep](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep)

```
if not_set:
    Time.sleep(60 * 60)        # 1 hour
if not_set:
    Time.sleep(60 * 60 * 2)    # 2 hours
if not_set:
    Time.sleep(60 * 60 * 4)    # 4 hours
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for the [`at`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_at.htm) command, you can find a little tutorial here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-job-scheduling/index.html

Basic usage:

```
at -f some_file_with_the_jobs.sh some_time
```

You can easily use relative times:

```
at -f some_file_with_the_jobs.sh  10pm tomorrow
```